# Can anyone solve this Interesting question

Tags: mathematics, visual

[image] can you solve this problem I don’t know

Comment: I’m voting to close this puzzle as purely mathematics, unless there’s some trick im missing, in which case it would probably be too broad.

Comment: @thecoder16 the 'trick' with these puzzles is usually that you have to pay attention how 'much' of a single unit is included in a picture. This one has so many deviations it's obvious and (IMHO) not fun anymore.

Answer (score 3):

> strawberry = 4
>  orange = 4/3
>  tomato = 10/3
>  therefore   4 * 4 * 10 / (3 * 3) = 160/9

Answer (score 1):

I think:

> strawberry = 4
> orange = 3/4
> tomato = 10/3
> 4 x 3/4 x 10/3 = 10